# Different WinForms DataGridView datasources without constant plumbing

Tags: c#, datagridview

In my application I have different datasources with different properties, which in most cases inherit from a base object and add some metadata. I can write some methods to handle validation and saving in a generic fashion for all my data objects, and I could do something similar for fetching the data. With use of attributes I can also make the dataobjects describe what they want to display in the `DataGridView`. Now what I can't seem to do is tell the `DataGridView` that there's a repository for these objects and that it should use that to fetch the dataobjects. I have been looking into the `DataObjectAttribute` and `DataObjectMethodAttribute`, but I can't find any way to tie it to a `DataGridView`.

Is there a feasible way to supply a `DataGridView` with a `DataSource` that makes the `DataGridView` know about fetching, saving and deleting my data objects?

Comment: try to format your question :)

Comment: Yes, good point. Also improved the actual question.